# Apache2 Virtual Host 503 error

Tags: apache2

Here is my apache2 virtual host config -

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName A.B.com
   ProxyPreserveHost Off 
   ProxyPass /  http://<ServerIP>:<appPort>/<app>/  timeout=3600 Keepalive=On
   ProxyPassReverse /  http://<ServerIP>:<appPort>/<app>/
   ProxyTimeout  3600
</VirtualHost>
<Location "/">
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
</Location>
```

I have a route 53 entry for A.B.com pointing to this machine (the one with apache2)

I have ran a2ensite.. I am getting a **503 service unavailable on hitting A.B.com**

However, A.B.com:appPort/app is working..

This definitely means I am missing something in apache2 configuration.. Can anyone point me out?

Answer (score 0):

ProxyPreserveHost Off
should be on, and not need to mention http://, but in route you can mention http://.

further please check and paste error logs.